# Passing a local variable from function to another - Automate the boring stuff practice

Tags: python-3.x, function

Just finished chapter 6 of Automate the Boring Stuff, and while doing the 'Table Printer' practice project, ran into some initial challenges around passing a variable defined in one function to another. After some online studying, think I got this right because the output seems correct. Please see code. Would appreciate advice on:

- Does what I have below makes sense? Or do you see any obvious errors that I missed
- Is there a better way to do this? (more concise / common practice, if what I have isn't the optimum way to write this code)

Just looking to learn and get better. Thank you!

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

def findMaxStringLength(list):
    value=0
    valList = []
    for i in range(len(list[0])): #assumes that all strings within the main string will have the same number of values in them (4 in this case)
        for j in range(len(list)):
            word = list[j][i]
            tempValue = len(word)
            valList = valList + [tempValue]
    value=int(max(valList))
    return value

def printTable(list):
    value = findMaxStringLength(list)
    for i in range(len(list[0])):                        
        for j in range(len(list)):
            print (list[j][i].rjust(value), end =' ')
        print()

printTable(tableData)
```

Output on shell:

```
  apples    Alice     dogs 
 oranges      Bob     cats 
cherries    Carol    moose 
  banana    David    goose
```

Comment: Why do you flip the table on output?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 Not sure what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: You flipped the rows and columns. See my answer below.

Comment: If your code works and you just want to make it "better" then you may want to post this on codereview instead.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Ah. I guess you mean here - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Didn't even know this existed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have seems fine to me. I would just do it differently, mainly because I am a different person. I am wondering though why your table is flipped on output.

How I did it is more concise, which is usually better. I also printed the table in the order its input. In general, it is better to directly iterate over the elements of a sequence (like a list) rather than getting an index and using that to extract the list's corresponding value. The rest is mainly the same.

Here is how I would do it:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

def findMaxStringLength(list):
    valList = []
    for lst in list: 
        valList.extend([len(x) for x in lst])
    value=max(valList)
    return value

def printTable(list):
    value = findMaxStringLength(list)
    for lst1 in list:                        
        for elem in lst1:
            print (elem.rjust(value), end =' ')
        print()

printTable(tableData)
```

Output:

```
  apples  oranges cherries   banana                                                                                                                            
   Alice      Bob    Carol    David                                                                                                                            
    dogs     cats    moose    goose
```

Comment: Thanks! Will review this code. Regarding flipping the table, I see what you mean. But, the book wanted the output to be in the order I had above.

Comment: @Philomath I see. then the version of `printTable` you have is fine.

Answer (score 0):

While iterating on a `range` can be Pythonic in some situations, it's often better to iterate over the contents of the list directly. Finding the lengths seems like a good match for a multi-loop generator expression that gets passed to `max`, while printing the table calls for `zip`:

```
def find_max_length(nested):    # this function ended up so short, you might just inline it
    return max(len(s) for inner in nested for s in inner)

def print_table(table):
    width = find_max_length(table)
    for row in zip(*table):
        print(*[s.rjust(width) for s in row])
```

I renamed the functions and some of the variables, for a mix of clarity and style reasons. It's a very bad idea to use `list` as a variable in your own code, as that shadows the name of the builtin list type. You may find yourself coming back to the code sometime later and trying to use the builtin `list`, only to get a confusing error message, since the name has been shadowed by some variable. You'll be surprised how quickly you forget the subtle details of your own code, if you're away from it for a while.

When it comes to style, a common Python style convention is to use `lowercase_names_with_underscores` for most variables and functions, and to reserve `CapitalizedNames` for classes. There isn't a whole lot of `camelCase` used, except for libraries and other code ported from other languages (where that's a more common style).

One note: The `zip` function will stop iterating as soon as it reaches the end of the shortest iterable you pass to it. If you might have lists in your table that are of different lengths, then you probably want to use `zip_longest` from the standard library module `itertools`, rather than the normal `zip`:

```
for row in itertools.zip_longest(*table, fillvalue=""):
    ...
```

The output will look like this:

```
>>> table_data = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana', 'pears'],
                  ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
                  ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose', 'owls', 'spiders']]

>>> print_table(table_data)
  apples    Alice     dogs
 oranges      Bob     cats
cherries    Carol    moose
  banana    David    goose
   pears              owls
                   spiders
```